# How to OR query expressions in XPATH

Tags: php, html, xpath

I'm trying to extract hrefs, srcs and value attributes from a HTML string using xpath

```
                $dom = new DOMDocument;  
                libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
                $dom->loadHTML (stripslashes ($content)); 
                $xpath = new DOMXPath ($dom);
                libxml_clear_errors();

                $doc = $dom->getElementsByTagName('html')->item(0);
                $srcs = $xpath->query('.//@src');
                $hrefs = $xpath->query ('.//@href');
                $values = $xpath->query ('.//@value');
```

How can I combine the xpath query expressions with OR ? This way I would have only have one array to traverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$stuff = $xpath->query('.//@src | //@href | //@value');`

| (or pipe) is the operator you're looking for.